# How to insert data into multiple SQL Server tables using C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio

I'm new joined this site. I have a little bit of a C# problem. I need to know how to insert data into multiple SQL Server tables using C#. English is not my mother language, so sorry if there are some spelling mistakes.

This is my C# code

```
try
{
    Sqlconn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = Sqlconn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into New_Vehicle values ('" + txt_id.Text + "', '" + txtV_No.Text + "', '" + txtE_No.Text + "', '" + dtm_Year.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "insert into New_Brand values ('" + txt_id.Text + "', '" + txtB_Name.Text + "', '" + txt_Model_Name.Text + "', '" + txtV_Type.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Sqlconn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Seve Record Succesfull", "Insert Message");
}
catch (Exception EX)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error" + EX);
}
```

This is the error I get when I run this code. Please help how to fix this problem

[image]

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: You need the new vehicle ID to create a brand. There are ways to get the ID from the result of the INSERT, I'll leave that for your research. However, it doesn't make sense that a brand would need a vehicle ID so I think you should re-think the database design. And also what @FranzGleichmann said.

Comment: Because the Insert statement gives an error with the Foreign Key (FK) for New_Brand, it may be because you are inserting the vehicle first then inserting the new brand. If you changed the order of the inserts (New_Brand then New_Vehicle) your code *might* work. As Austin said, it's not possible to tell without seeing table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through each table with a foreach loop and run the insert code you have there but use the table name from the foreach loop

for this to work, you would need a list of table objects, each with a property called "Name" which contains the name of the table that matches the table name in the database

```
    foreach (var table in List_Of_Tables)
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into " + table.Name + " values ('" + txt_id.Text + "', '" + txtV_No.Text + "', '" + txtE_No.Text + "', '" + dtm_Year.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```